# Ajax syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

Im trying to implement this code, and when I run my local server I get a syntax error.  I am running rails version 3.2.11 and thinking maybe that has something to do with this code.

```
<h1>Time Ajax Demo</h1>
<p><%= link_to 'Get Current Time', time_refresh_path, 
     remote: true %>
</p>
<p id='currentTime'>
Current time will appear here
</p>
```

This is my error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
     remote: true );@output_buffer.safe_concat('
```

Comment: Are you using Ruby 1.9?

Answer (score 0):

Try `link_to 'Get Current Time', time_refresh_path, :remote => true`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using ruby `1.8.X`. If you are using Ruby version less than `1.9.X` use `=>`:

```
<%= link_to 'Get Current Time', time_refresh_path, :remote => true %>
```